# Is having only one argument functions efficient? Haskell

Tags: performance, function, haskell, arguments

I have started learning Haskell and I have read that every function in haskell takes only one argument and I can't understand what magic happens under the hood of Haskell that makes it possible and I am wondering if it is efficient.

#### Example

---

```
>:t (+)
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Signature above means that `(+)` function takes one `Num` then returns another function which takes one `Num` and returns a `Num`

---

**Example 1** is relatively easy but I have started wondering what happens when functions are a little more complex.

#### My Questions

---

For sake of the example I have written a `zipWith` function and executed it in two ways, once passing one argument at the time and once passing all arguments.

```
zipwithCustom f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : zipwithCustom f xs ys
zipwithCustom _ _ _ = []
zipWithAdd = zipwithCustom (+)
zipWithAddTo123 = zipWithAdd [1,2,3]

test1 = zipWithAddTo123 [1,1,1]
test2 = zipwithCustom (+) [1,2,3] [1,1,1]

>test1
[2,3,4]
>test2
[2,3,4]
```

1. Is passing one argument at the time *(scenario_1)* as efficient as passing all arguments at once *(scenario_2)*?
2. Are those scenarios any different in terms of what Haskell is actually doing to compute `test1` and `test2` (except the fact that scenario_1 probably takes more memory as it needs to save `zipWithAdd` and `zipWithAdd123`)
3. Is this correct and why? In *scenario_1* I iterate over `[1,2,3]` and then over `[1,1,1]`
4. Is this correct and why? In *scenario_1* and *scenario_2* I iterate over both lists at the same time

I realise that I have asked a lot of questions in one post but I believe those are connected and will help me (and other people who are new to Haskell) to better understand what actually is happening in Haskell that makes both scenarios possible.

Comment: in both scenario's you iterate over both lists at the same time.

Comment: in `test2` you also each time called it with one parameter, since `zipWithCustom (+) [1,2,3] [1,1,1]` is short for `((zipWithCustom (+)) [1,2,3]) [1,1,1]`.

Comment: Related: [Why is Haskell (GHC) so darn fast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35027952/why-is-haskell-ghc-so-darn-fast)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Do you know any nice sources I could read to understand how that happens? I am intrigued by what Haskell is doing to make it possible to run code inside  the body of `zipwithCustom` function `f x y : zipwithCustom f xs ys` when it is taking only one parameter at the time. Does it just wait with execution until it has all the parameters?

Comment: @hdw3: it does not run the function. haskell is *lazy*. It will under the hood only perform something when necessary, and when you thus enumerate over the list, you have passed the `f` and the lists.

Comment: @hdw3: but more importantly, the idea is that if you call `zipWithCustom (+)` you simply construct a *new* function that will take the list, and then one that will take the other list. So `zipWith (+)` basically constructs a *new* function, not a list.

Comment: Some type checking subtleties aside, a definition like `foo x = ...` isn't really different than `foo = \x -> ...` `zipWithCustom (+)` is a function that takes a list and returns a new function in both `zipWithAdd = ...` and `test2 = ...`. The only real difference is that in the latter, the function is immediately applied to `[1,2,3]` (and *that* result is immediately applied to `[1,1,1]`.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You ask about "Haskell", but Haskell the language specification doesn't care about these details. It is up to implementations to choose how evaluation happens -- the only thing the spec says is what the result of the evaluation should be, and carefully avoids giving an algorithm that must be used for computing that result. So in this answer I will talk about GHC, which, practically speaking, is the only extant implementation.

For (3) and (4) the answer is simple: the iteration pattern is exactly the same whether you apply `zipWithCustom` to arguments one at a time or all at once. (And that iteration pattern is to iterate over both lists at once.)

Unfortunately, the answer for (1) and (2) is **complicated**.

The starting point is the following simple algorithm:

1. When you apply a function to an argument, a *closure* is created (allocated and initialized). A closure is a data structure in memory, containing a pointer to the function and a pointer to the argument. When the function body is executed, any time its argument is mentioned, the value of that argument is looked up in the closure.
2. That's it.

However, this algorithm kind of sucks. It means that if you have a 7-argument function, you allocate 7 data structures, and when you use an argument, you may have to follow a 7-long chain of pointers to find it. Gross. So GHC does something slightly smarter. It uses the syntax of your program in a special way: if you apply a function to multiple arguments, it generates just one closure for that application, with as many fields as there are arguments.

(Well... that might be not quite true. Actually, it tracks the *arity* of every function -- defined again in a syntactic way as the number of arguments used to the left of the `=` sign when that function was defined. If you apply a function to more arguments than its arity, you might get multiple closures or something, I'm not sure.)

So that's pretty nice, and from that you might think that your `test1` would then allocate one extra closure compared to `test2`. And you'd be right... when the optimizer isn't on.

But GHC also does lots of optimization stuff, and one of those is to notice "small" definitions and inline them. Almost certainly with optimizations turned on, your `zipWithAdd` and `zipWithAddTo123` would both be inlined anywhere they were used, and we'd be back to the situation where just one closure gets allocated.

Hopefully this explanation gets you to where you can answer questions (1) and (2) yourself, but just in case it doesn't, here's explicit answers to those:

> 1. Is passing one argument at the time as efficient as passing all arguments at once?

Maybe. It's possible that passing arguments one at a time will be converted via inlining to passing all arguments at once, and then of course they will be identical. In the absence of this optimization, passing one argument at a time has a (very slight) performance penalty compared to passing all arguments at once.

> 2. Are those scenarios any different in terms of what Haskell is actually doing to compute `test1` and `test2`?

`test1` and `test2` will almost certainly be compiled to the same code -- possibly even to the point that only one of them is compiled and the other is an alias for it.

If you want to read more about the ideas in the implementation, the [Spineless Tagless G-machine](http://twister.43foldrs.com/spineless-tagless-gmachine.pdf) paper is much more approachable than its title suggests, and only a little bit out of date.

Comment: Most importantly, in the OP example the "(very slight) performance penalty" only occurs once for the whole list, even if `zipwithCustom` uses the closure many times.